# Ubuntu 18.04 Server Static IP issues

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, static-ip, netplan

I have attempted setting up a static IP for a server, under Ubuntu 18.04. I thought I had it working, but after restarting I found that my ethernet interface `eno1` has been disabled. After re-enabling with `sudo ifconfig eno1 up`, it fails to get a IPv4 ip address.

I setup the static ip using the new netplan system (config below), and had it working with this configuration, but I no longer see netplan installed (`sudo netplan apply` yields `netplan: command not found`).

To summarize, two issues:

- the interface was disabled and no longer gets IPv4
- netplan is no longer installed?

Contents of `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.5/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
```

I know it is probably not a network issue as I am able to use other computers (albiet via dhcp) just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that netplan has been uninstalled for some reason.

Run these commands to re-install netplan:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install netplan.io
```

Reboot the machine. After that your configuration in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` should be processed.